# how to remove items from an perl array based using grep and shift?

Tags: perl

I need to remove the data record symbol and any blank lines in a dataRecord using perl.

for example,

```
$/ = "__Data__"

__Data__
riririririr
djkfkdfjkdjkf
dghghghghghghg
(blank line)

     my @dataRecord = split(/\n/);
     grep(/(__Data__|/,@dataRecord);
```

How do I remove the items I do not want in the array based on the grep filtering?

Comment: Has to be some error in that code... Doesn't make much sense in Perl...

Comment: After using perl's grep function, how do I remove the items I don't want in the array?

Comment: grep returns the list of items that you do want. It doesn't filter an array in-place. @dataRecord = grep(/(__Data__|/, @dataRecord);

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
my @filered_list = grep { length( $_ ) and $_ ne '__Data__' } @dataRecord;
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what's going on with the input record separator here, and the use of split is not valid unless the implicit `$_` is being used.

---

To answer the question though, use the `!` operator to negate the sense of the match:

```
@dataRecord = grep { ! /__Data__|^$/ } @dataRecord;
```

The `!` can also be replaced with `not` for this case:

```
@dataRecord = grep { not /__Data__|^$/ } @dataRecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the elements that match the criteria:

```
@dataRecord = grep(/expr/,@dataRecord);
```

(assuming that the elements that you don't want in the array are the ones that don't pass the matching regex).

Comment: How do I grep for a blank line?

Comment: `grep(/^$/,@dataRecord)` selects all empty lines.